# Custom Post Type Link added to menu won't show in frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have created a custom post type and I want to link directly to some of the posts in the custom post type in my main navigation menu.

I can see the posts in the left hand side of the menu page, and can add the posts to my main menu, however the link does not appear in the frontend of the website after saving.

After saving the link is still there in the menu view in the admin panel.

Here are the labels and arguments I pass to the `register_post_type` function:

```
public $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Special Offers',
    'singular_name'      => 'Special Offer',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New Special Offer',
    'all_items'          => 'All Special Offers',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Offer',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Offer',
    'new_item'           => 'New Offer',
    'view_item'          => 'View Offer',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Special Offers',
    'not_found'          =>  'No Offers found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Offers found in trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Offer:',
    'menu_name'          => 'Special Offers'
);

public $args = array(
    'description'         => "",
    'public'              => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true, 
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true, 
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 26,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'supports'            => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'specialoffers')
);
```

Everything else works perfectly with my custom post type.

Please can anyone suggest a way to make the custom post type links appear in my main menu, or diagnose the problem for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was very simple, I was accidentally adding my `register_post_type()` function within an `is_admin()` condition, therefore on the public facing side of the website the post type was never registered, hence it not showing up.

Comment: Glad you figured it out and thanks for posting your answer. +1. Just on that, this is why it is always important to post as much code that is directly relevant to your question. This could have been sorted within a couple of minutes :-) Enjoy